# XML to Json Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, xml, xml2js

I'm using xml2js npm to parse xml to json and everything goes well except in xml file, there is an attribute key

```
<ht:approx_traffic>20,000+</ht:approx_traffic>
```

and xml2js parses it in json like this

```
"ht:approx_traffic": [
   "20,000+"
]
```

Is there a way that I can get rid of the colon there? Thanks.

I just simply use this to parse

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    xml2js = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/foo.xml', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        console.dir(result);
        console.log('Done');
    });
});
```

Comment: so you want `approx_traffic`?

Comment: You want to get rid of the colon? That would mean that the JSON and the XML differ key-wise.

Comment: yeah. But I can't seem to figure out

Comment: There's a potential option in the xml2js library: `stripPrefix: strips the xml namespace prefix. E.g <foo:Bar/> will become 'Bar'. (N.B.: the xmlns prefix is NOT stripped.)` see [https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js#processing-attribute-tag-names-and-values](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js#processing-attribute-tag-names-and-values).

Comment: answer to your deleted question can be found here http://nsdateformatter.com

Comment: @vacawama thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `stripPrefix` processor.

```
var stripPrefix = require('xml2js').processors.stripPrefix;

parser.parseString(
  data,
  { tagNameProcessors: [stripPrefix] },
  function(err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
    console.log('Done');
  }
);
```

Read the spec [here](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/blob/0f0a2980b3db5366b3d50e4d0da422cb7af100c9/README.md#processing-attribute-tag-names-and-values). Working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/50mp0qrn8n).

Comment: Some how, I received this error
ReferenceError: processors is not defined

Comment: Got it fixed. Thank you!